# How to delete ALL notes from Stickies app?

Tags: keyboard, finder, macos, stickies

Eventually I need to clean house when too many Stickies notes accumulate, but it seems harder than necessary. Is there an easy way?

Mac OS allows many windows to be closed at once using option-command-w (Finder Get Info windows, open folders, open Preview windows (even if edits have been made)). But this does not work with Stickies. And since they all have content, you get prompted to save every time command-w is used. So the only way I know is to command-w, spacebar, command-w, spacebar, command-w, spacebar, etc... As you can see in the animated .gif, this gets old.

Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: Can you please use a static picture instead of the GIF, it's rather uncomfortable to watch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method works for me at least. macOS 10.14.5

```
rm ~/Library/StickiesDatabase
```

---

Using Automator's Record feature, you can ease repetitive tasks.

1. First get a new workflow. Then hit record button on the top right. This makes a floating record bar with a stop button and gives focus to Finder.
2. Click the Stickies in the Dock and click the stop button in the Automator bar.
3. This opens Automator with a single action in a block, *Running* which gives focus to Stickies/ or opens it.

   [image: Automator's single block]
4. Now hit the record button and

   1. Click Stickies in the dock: this opens all the notes.
   2. Hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> OR File menu > close note.
   3. Click Delete note in the popup that appears.
   4. Stop the recording.

   Now you should have this on your screen.

   [image]
5. Click on the "Click "Stickies" in the dock line" in the second block and hit delete.
6. You can also increase the playback speed. Now the second block is ready to be copied. So click on the black area to get focus of the same.

   1. Either right click, hit duplicate. Then use command key to select multiple blocks, right click duplicate, and repeat as many times you wish.

   [image]

   2. Simply <kbd>command</kbd> + click on the blocks and use normal copy paste shortcuts.

   [image]

Now save it and run it. When it runs out of notes, it encounters an error, and terminates.

Comment: **1** I am on Mojave. Stickies, upon opening,  makes that file in the said folder. You can enter that path in Finder > cmd + shift + G  and browse it yourself. You can also use search to find "stickies" folder in `~/Library` folder and remove it. Careful to not tamper with `/Library` folder.

Comment: See updated answer for automator.

Comment: On a mac extended keyboard there are 2 keys labeled "delete".  One of them works as you describe, but the other does not -- rather than deleting a single command, it deletes the whole item. For that reason, I was not able to get through the first time you explained. Your explanation is excellent because now I understand how to use Automator better. It's a little slow because of the mouse moves, even though I increased "playback speed" to 10x, and I would prefer to use a true loop than the copy/paste. But I appreciate what I've learned, so thanks again.

Comment: "*rather than deleting a single command, it deletes the whole item.*" maybe the focus is on the block, not on the one line you want to delete.

Comment: Also, if you see the script which you obtain as described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542826/applescript-editor-record-doesnt-work/18752770#18752770 here, you'll see that the delay is the same as what you originally did. So you can reduce that in the script, copy that script > make a new "run AppleScript" block > paste it there and then again increase speed.